# Breadboard arduino uno not working properly

Tags: arduino-uno, breadboard

[image]Is there any mistake in the circuit of arduino uno on breadboard... I am using arduino uno board to program this 328p mcu and after that i remove 328p from arduino uno board and placing on breadboard as shown in circuit diagram. But mcu is not working(i.e the motors are not and other devices connected to mcu are not working) But when i connect reset,vcc,gnd pins of 328p on breadboard to arduino uno board without 328p on it then its working fine and all devices are working according to my program.. even when  i connect those reset,vcc and gnd pins to reset,vcc,gnd of  any usb asp programmer then also its working fine(*even programmer is not plugged in to pc). Its very strange behavior even if i disconnect any of these reset,vcc,gnd cables then also its not working... Is there any errors in circuit...please help me out[image: , breadboard]

Comment: That schematic is very hard to follow. You should use GND and VCC symbols instead of nets for your power and ground.

Comment: @Majenko i have added another circuit of eliminating  devices connected to it.. can you have a look at it..

Comment: Does it have to have all three connections to the Uno? Have you tried all different combinations of connections to see which work and which don't?

Comment: yes reset,vcc,gnd pins of 328p on breadboard has to connect same pins of any programmer usbasp or uno board with empty 328p..

Comment: Try measuring the voltage at the reset pin. It sounds like something on your board is pulling the reset line low. Also you schematic uses a weird symbol for the reset pins pull-up resistor.

Comment: Again i have verified the reset circuit... i found that after powering on the code is not running.. i have manualy reset 328p by sorting reset pin to ground .. then the code works fines... whats the problem in my circuit? i have to manually reset every time to get it working.. is the any thing to implement in my circuit that it can automatically reset at power on..

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by adding 100nf capacitor between reset and ground.... Which enables a auto reset function after every time powering on..
[from this arduino forum i got this solution](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=107140.0#msg804230)

Thank you everyone